# What control is used as inline listbox on windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, wpf-controls

Cannot find appropriate control in standard set. Probably there is some third party realization?
It looks like textbox until you click it. Then it expands to show available options. The good example is background color selector in windows phone settings.
[example img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuEQA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Represents a selection control that combines a non-editable text box and a drop-down list box that allows users to select an item from a list.

[How to add a combo box (XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868195.aspx)

Comment: I usually use the ListPicker in the Windows Phone Toolkit